# Diffusion-reaction model using reactran in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement a reaction-diffusion PDE using reacTran in the deSolve package. However, the time-dependent reaction term is not working. Any suggestions on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(ReacTran)
library(deSolve)

N <- 1000
xgrid <- setup.grid.1D(x.up = 0, x.down = 10, N = N)
x <- xgrid$x.mid
D.coeff <- 1
k <- 1

Diffusion <- function (t, Y, parms){
  tran <- tran.1D(C = Y, C.up = 0, C.down = 0, D = D.coeff, dx = xgrid)-k*t
  reac <- -kt
  return(list(tran$dC+reac))
}

# Set initial conditions as gaussian distribution
C0 <- 10            #Initial concentration (mg/L)
X0 <- 5             #Location of initial concentration (m)
sig <- .2           #Spread of Gaussian distribution
C <- rep(0,N)       #matrix
Yini <- C+C0*exp(-((x-X0)/sig)^2)

parms1 <- list(D=D.coeff, k=k)

times <- seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = 0.01)
print(system.time(
  out <- ode.1D(y = Yini, times = times, func = Diffusion,
            parms = parms1, dimens = N)))
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? You should ask a specific programming question. Make it clear what the problem is you are having.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The "out" does not change when the k*t term is added either at the end of the tran.1D expression or as the reac term.